# Composer Playground Profiles?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

When you use Playground tied to a Connection Profile of your Fabric, meaning running Playground Locally, you're able to deploy your own chaincode, and issue identities. Since you do so as PeerAdmin, and you can manage your wallet with different identities, are those identities Local? If I check the Playground from another device, I have the same wallet there, with PeerAdmin rights.

So, is it possible to run playground with the same chaincode in different devices but with different roles, identities or wallets? In a similar fashion as how it is when you use the RestAPI with OAuth, where you can establish each participant as an identity, using the same API "address".

I guess it maybe possible to run a local instance of playground in another device and establish the connection profile to the remote one and then it would have a different wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playground uses a local credential store, by default stored in the user's home directory, which may be on the host, or inside a Docker container, depending how you are running Playground.

We are working on designs for how credentials can be imported/exported from Playground at the moment. You can follow progress here:
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/902